# Why doesn't the same CSS code work in an external file?

Tags: html, css

This piece of code in a file called index.html just sets the background of the page to be light blue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body
    </body>
</html>
```

When I put it in a file called stylesheet.css in the same directory however, and link it using an href, the background remains white. Here is the html and css files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"> 
    </head>

    <body
    </body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

What's going on here? How come it doesn't work the same way?

Answer (score 6):

In an external stylesheet, you don't need the `<style>` tag.  So, the contents of your external stylesheet should simply be

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that works. Why don't I need the <style> tag? Thank you so much!!

Comment: @user3835653 The style tag is an HTML element. CSS files should just contain CSS rules. Including markup in the CSS file makes it invalid. You probably want to review something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS

Comment: The browser knows that the contents of an external stylesheet will be CSS (you tell it when you create the `<link>` tag).  So the `<style>` tag is not needed.